# Tryinf to iterate a Map, how to keep track of the number of iterations?

Tags: java, android

I have a Tree Map:

```
Map<Date, String> Sx = new TreeMap<Date, String>();
```

I populate it using  aLoader and keep on adding values, now I retrieve these values like:

```
 if(Sx.isEmpty() != true){
        for (Map.Entry<Date,String> entry : Sx.entrySet()) {

            //Some logic
 }
```

How do I know the number of iteration I am currently processing? Something like the int i from the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your own:

```
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Date,String> entry : Sx.entrySet()) {
    //Some logic
    i++;
}

Log.d(TAG, "I've been through the loop " + i + " times");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way.

Given that you write your own Index class and a static method that returns an Iterable over instances of this class you can

```
for (Index<String> each: With.index(stringArray)) {
    each.value;
    each.index;
    ...
}
```

Where the implementation of With.index is something like

```
class With {
    public static <T> Iterable<Index<T>> index(final T[] array) {
        return new Iterable<Index<T>>() {
            public Iterator<Index<T>> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<Index<T>>() {
                    index = 0;
                    public boolean hasNext() { return index < array.size }
                    public Index<T> next() { return new Index(array[index], index++); }
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More code, more errors! Id go with the other one. Nevertheless Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: There is always easy way and clean way :)